# Lightbox in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, lightbox

I want to have lightbox gallery in my Wordpress site.. How do i do that, because with simple examples it doedn't work.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you don't tell us what is not working when you tried out simple examples I can only point you to a plugin. Use [Lightbox 2](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/lightbox-2/) to enable Lightbox galleries in your Wordpress site. If you still struggle with the integration have a look at the [FAQ](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/lightbox-2/faq/) of that plugin.

Comment: the photos appear in the bottom of the page when I click on the thumbnail

Comment: Sounds like CSS is not loading - can you post a URL? What theme are you using? Is there a stylesheet such as `lightbox.css` when you view source?

Comment: Did you try to switch to another theme for testing purposes? If the problem does not persist you should have a look at the CSS of your theme regarding the selectors for images.